# How to add a live demo button to a wooCommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, elementor, custom-button

I want to add a custom button to product page that will be used to show the live demo of product by inserting custom link in each product, which is just an URL that changes by each product (to open live demo for each product separately). Can anyone help me in this. I have attached a link and an image for reference.

[image: Demo image for what I want]

See here : https://theme9.net/theme/generatepress-premium-activation-with-key-lifetime

I tried to add it using Advance custom fields. I don't know, somehow it is not displaying. I am able see an option for custom button and url in dashboard. But it is not reflecting on front end.